# How do I match a string starting at a specific position in the string?

Tags: c#, regex

What is the regex for matching a date starting at the 4th position? I want it to return just the date and not the whole match. This is what I have.

```
^.{4}[2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-9]{2}
DCSG20170406090204-FQI-046.TOT  04-FIC-046    00060Y000815050.562500G
DCS120170406090204-FQI-045.TOT  04-FIC-045    00060Y000878279.312500G
DCS120170406090204-FQI-046.TOT  04-FIC-046    00060Y000815050.562500G
```

http://regexr.com/3g0d5

Comment: The date is `201704060`? Maybe `^DCSG?1?(20\d+)` if that format is consistent.

Comment: How about just `string.Substring` ?

Comment: @chris85 Not sure what happened there but it seems to be working now.

Comment: @chris85 Oops I see what you mean now. Passive aggressiveness does pay off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a non-capturing group:

```
^(?:.{4})([2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-9]{2})(?:.*)$
```

(mouse over the text at: http://regexr.com/3g0db and it will show just one group)

Comment: I changed it to [2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9] with plans to have dates further validated

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C#, but from my Perl perspective, I don't see any need for a regular expression.  If you just want "the date" and don't need to validate it or separate it into components, just get the substring starting at position 4 (0 based) and 8 characters long.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can use substring but just got a bit curious.